# Replicating a remote database from Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

Database URL:
   https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$REMOTE_USERNAME.Cloudant.com/$DATABASE_NAME

What is the value of $USERNAME、$PASSWORD、$REMOTE_USERNAME?
[image]

[image]

The current Cloudant account:

```
VCAP_SERVICES
{
    "cloudantNoSQLDB": [
        {
            "credentials": {
                "username": "c39cexxx-bluemix",
                "password": "xxxxxxx",
                "host": "c39cexxx-bluemix.cloudant.com",
                "port": 443,
                "url": "https://c39cexxx-bluemix:xxxxxxx@c39cexxx-bluemix.cloudant.com"
            },  
        }
    ]
}


The other Cloudant accounts in a database
VCAP_SERVICES
{
    "cloudantNoSQLDB": [
        {
            "credentials": {
                "username": "f39c4xxx-bluemix",
                "password": "xxxxxxx",
                "host": "f39c4xxx-bluemix.cloudant.com",
                "port": 443,
                "url": "https://f39c4xxx-bluemix:xxxxxxx@f39c4xxx-        bluemix.cloudant.com"
            },  
        }
    ]
}
```

Please give an example of replicating a remote database from Bluemix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replicate from a remote target into a local database, your Database URL will be:

```
https://$remote_username:$remote_password@$remote_username.cloudant.com/$remote_database
```

E.g.

```
https://f39c45g0-bluemix:0ebdc6c7@f39c45g0-bluemix.cloudant.com/the_remote_database
```

You can find more information here: https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/cloudant-replication/

---

***NOTE***: I'm assuming you didn't post your actual credentials, if you did you should at least change your passwords.

Comment: @Olivia :  Haven't given this a try in a while, but there is also a cloud foundry CLI plugin (https://github.com/ibmjstart/bluemix-cloudant-replicator) that could be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Chris snow.

Comment: Np.  If this worked for you Olivia, please accept the answer and an upvote would be nice too :)